# Pandas datetime operations optimization

Tags: pandas, datetime

I would like to generate a column "days_to_christmas". I wrote this function but it is not elegant in my opinion.

```
def xmas(x):
    if x < pd.datetime(2015,12,21):
        return (pd.datetime(2015,12,21) - x).days
    elif x < pd.datetime(2016,12,21):
        return (pd.datetime(2016,12,21) - x).days
    elif x < pd.datetime(2017,12,21):
        return (pd.datetime(2017,12,21) - x).days
    elif x < pd.datetime(2018,12,21):
        return (pd.datetime(2018,12,21) - x).days
    else:
        return (pd.datetime(2019,12,21) - x).days
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

My earlier answer did not handle the year wrap around, here is a version that does it:

```
def days_to_day_month(date, month, day):
    if (date.month == month and date.day > day):
        return (pd.datetime(date.year+1, month, day)-date).days
    else:
        return (pd.datetime(date.year, month, day)-date).days
```

To calculate the days to christmas call it like so:

```
days_to_day_month(date, 12, 21)
```

Or built a default around it:

```
days_to_christmas(date):
    return days_to_day_month(date, 12, 21)
```

Then you just can call:

```
days_to_christmas(date)
```

The only thing I don't get is: Isn't Christmas on the 24th of December instead of the 21th?

Answer (score 1):

if the date is after 21-Dec then get days till next year's christmas else this year's christmas

```
def days_to_christmas(d):
    next_christmas = date(d.year+1, 12, 21) \
           if d.month == 12 and d.day >= 21 else date(d.year, 12, 21)
    return (next_christmas - d).days
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input data is confined to years 2015 to 2019, then you can use this statement.

```
np.random.seed(123)
s = pd.DataFrame({'date':np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2015-01-01','2019-12-31',freq='D'),10)})
```

Using lambda function:

```
s['days_to_christmas'] = s['date'].apply(lambda x: (pd.to_datetime(str(x.year)+'-12-21')-x).days)
```

or defined function:

```
def xmas(x):
    return (pd.to_datetime(str(x.year)+'-12-21')-x).days

s['days_to_christmas'] = s['date'].apply(xmas)
```

Output:

```
        date  days_to_christmas
0 2015-05-27                208
1 2016-04-29                236
2 2018-07-19                155
3 2017-09-30                 82
4 2016-02-16                309
5 2019-11-25                 26
6 2015-06-08                196
7 2018-04-19                246
8 2019-05-26                209
9 2018-10-21                 61
```